# How to solve Error with switch Function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I am trying to create a function that gives me the month depending on the console.log info.

```
    function daysInMonth(month) {
  switch (month) {
    case '1': case '3': case '5': case '7': case '8': case '10': case '12':
      return '31';
    case '2':
      return '28';
    case '4': case '6': case '9': case '11':
      return '30';
    default:
      return 'You have to put a month from 1 to 12';
  }
}
var result = daysInMonth('1');
var result = daysInMonth('6');
var result = daysInMonth('2');
```

I am given some errors:

Log
31
30
28
function daysInMonth (month)
function daysInMonth should be declared
should return 31 when month is one of the following values: 1,3,5,7,8,10,12
function should return 31 when month is one of the following 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
: expected 'You have to put a month from 1 to 12' to equal 31
Completed in 2ms
should return 30 when month is one of the following values: 4, 6, 9, 11
function should return 30 when month is one of the following 4, 6, 9, 11
: expected 'You have to put a month from 1 to 12' to equal 30
should return 28 when month is 2
function should return 28 when month is 2
: expected 'You have to put a month from 1 to 12' to equal 28

This is what I was asked to do:

Implement the logic of the function named daysInMonth. The function receives one argument month, which is an integer (whole number) in the range from 1 to 12.

It should return a number of days depending on the month of the year, as per the given table:

+-----------------+------------+
|      month      |    days    |
+-----------------+------------+
| 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 |     31     |
+-----------------+------------+
| 4,6,9,11        |     30     |
+-----------------+------------+
| 2               |     28     |
+-----------------+------------+
Important: You must use the keyword return to return the value from the function. Tests can only check the output value that your function returns. Any console.log output will be ignored.

I made the changes with the return, as I was assuming I had to console.log everything. Still, errors occur.
Can you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your repo url because your code is working fine ,so  it will be difficult to find actual problem?

Comment: _"function should return 28 when month is 2"_: you're not returning anything from the function, you're just logging strings.

Comment: You're saying that now that the function returns the result as intended, you're still getting errors? What errors are you receiving? Please give us more context.

Answer (score 0):

I was defining a string when I was supposed to define cases as integers. Re-read the request and got to that conclusion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).